# Domain of composite of three functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

My question is if we want to find the domain of
$[(f\circ g\circ h)](x) $
Will the domain be the Dom of the constructed(new) function intersection with the Dom of $(g(h(x))$ intersection with the Dom of $h(x)$.

Comment: I don't understand why you think it would be anything different than the domain of $f$.  If $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$ and $g$ is a function from $B$ to $C$ then you have $f\circ g$ is a function from $A$ to $C$.  Composing this again with $h$ a function from $C$ to $D$ makes $f\circ g\circ h$ a function from $A$ to $D$...  Are you perhaps thinking of a scenario where $g$ is *not* a function from $B$ and there are elements in the range of $f$ for which $g$ is not defined?

Comment: Also, since I see you wrote $g(h(x))$... it is worth confirming... are you following the notation that $(f\circ g)(x) = g(f(x))$?  Or are you using here this is instead $(f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$?  I may have gotten it backwards then, in which case just take what I wrote above and rearrange the function names... but it would still wind up being the domain of the composition is the domain of the "first" function in the chain.

Comment: Yes Assume that f is from A to B and g from C to D where D contains elements not in A and A also contains elements not in D

Comment: (fog)(x)=f(g(x))

Comment: Then why should you be allowed to compose the functions in the first place if the codomain of the first doesn't match the domain of the second?  What you are doing isn't composing functions... its like a "restricted composition" of functions...

Comment: It is a composition of functions but the question in the textbook asking to state to restrict the domain if it is needed

Comment: So when I explained to my students I gave them what I mentioned in my question

Comment: @Well defined $h$ , $g \circ h $ , $ f \circ g \circ h $ all have same domain,,,so, why do you want to insect them???

Comment: They don't have the same Domain as what I mentioned in my comment , the questuons in the textbook asking to composite the function with restriction of the domain if it is needed

Answer (score 0):

When defining composite functions, it is reasonable to expect the image of the first function to atleast have some intersection with the domain of the second. We can then define the composition, $g \circ h$ on the smaller $h^{-1}(Dom(g))$.

One might think that there should be some $Dom (g) \cap Im(h)$ involved. But this set is just $h^{-1}(Dom(g))$, because on the points of $Dom(g)$ that don't lie in $Im(h)$, the inverse image doesn't exist.

Extending this to three functions, we can only define the composition on **$h^{-1}(g^{-1}(Dom(f))$**.

The following inclusion holds:  **$$h^{-1}(g^{-1}(Dom(f)) \subset h^{-1}(Dom(g)) \subset Dom(h)$$**.

So, the set mentioned by the OP is actually the set **$h^{-1}(g^{-1}(Dom(f))$**, which is the domain of $f\circ g \circ h$.

Comment: Range of (h) is a subset of domain g and range of (goh) is a subset of domain f  isn't this same as what I mentioned in my question the case of intersection

Answer (score 0):

The domain of $(f \circ g \circ h ) $ will be the domain of $h$,as $(g \circ h) $ is possible iff $Range(h) ⊂ Dom(g) $ and again , $(f \circ g \circ h ) $  is possible iff $Range(g \circ h) ⊂ Dom(f) $

Comment: Range of (h) is a subset of domain g and range of (goh) is a subset of domain f isn't this same as what I mentioned in my question the case of intersection

Comment: Domain of the new function intersect with the domain of g(h(x)) intersect with the domain of h(x) I think it is still the same as what you mentioned in your answer

Comment: But in the composition of three functions it doesn't depend only on the x values in h as  the h(x) Range values will move you to g(h(x)) so the x values in the domain of h(x) maybe will be undefined in the g(x)

Comment: As JMoravitz says, if $h: A \to B $ and $g: B \to C $ , then $g \circ h : A \to C $ , iff $Range(h)⊂ Domain(g) $....But , $Range(h)⊂ Domain(g) $ doesn't effect to the domain of the composite function..

Comment: But if h : A-> B   and g:C->D then goh: we need to find the x values in the function h whose range values are a subset of the domain of g

Comment: Hmmm,,, right,,,but it doesn't matter with the domain of compsite function,,,,this rule only for whether composite possible or not,,,but if the composite is possible,,,the domain will be the domain of starter function..

Comment: Okk, take a example,,,take $h=x^2 $ on $\mathbb{R} $ , and $g=\sqrt{x} $ on $[0,\infty) $,,, clearly $g\circ h = x $ have domain $\mathbb{R} $ , where $Range(h)=Domain (g) = [0,\infty) $,,, clearly you see domain of $g \circ h$ only depend on the domain of $h$...

Comment: So in your example if I asked you to find h(g(-1))  will the answer be undefined or -1?

Comment: It's for $g \circ h = g(h(x)) $,,,and if you go for $h \circ g $ ,,, then it is undefined!!! As the rule range (g) not in domain of (h).....so, there is no meaning of finding $h(g(-1))$

Comment: So this is what I meant  that for the new constructed function from composition must be restricted as what I memtioned in my Question